# Moving photos and renaming them if they exist?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to move photos from directories to one directory with find. It works good:

```
find /origin/path \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.jpeg' -o -iname '*.JPG' -o -iname '*.JPEG' -o -iname '*.PNG' -o -iname '*.png' -o -iname '*.gif' -o -iname '*.GIF' \) -type f -exec mv -nv -t /final/path -- {} +;
```

How to rename files if they have the same name (but different photos)?

Comment: Is this how we welcome new users? When they ask a proper, on-topic shell scripting question we effectively tell them go away by closing the question as off-topic? Yes I know that we get an enormous amount of low quality crap questions from new users that should be closed. This is not one of them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--backup=t` option for mv. This will append an increasing numbered suffix to files whose target already exists.

```
$ find /tmp/test -type f
/tmp/test/dir2/image.jpg
/tmp/test/dir3/image.jpg
/tmp/test/dir1/image.jpg
/tmp/test/dir4/image.jpg
$ mkdir /tmp/test2
$ find /tmp/test -iname '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -0 mv -v --backup=t --target-directory=/tmp/test2
‘/tmp/test/dir2/image.jpg’ -> ‘/tmp/test2/image.jpg’
‘/tmp/test/dir3/image.jpg’ -> ‘/tmp/test2/image.jpg’ (backup: ‘/tmp/test2/image.jpg.~1~’)
‘/tmp/test/dir1/image.jpg’ -> ‘/tmp/test2/image.jpg’ (backup: ‘/tmp/test2/image.jpg.~2~’)
‘/tmp/test/dir4/image.jpg’ -> ‘/tmp/test2/image.jpg’ (backup: ‘/tmp/test2/image.jpg.~3~’)
$
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry i didn't because i'm on windows now, but below script should do it

```
files_list=$(find /origin/path \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.jpeg' -o -iname '*.JPG' -o -iname '*.JPEG' -o -iname '*.PNG' -o -iname '*.png' -o -iname '*.gif' -o -iname '*.GIF' \) -type f)

for file in ${files_list}
do
    counter=0
    while true
    do
        if [[ ! -a ${file} ]]
        then
            mv "${file}" "/final/path/${file}"
            break
        else
            file="${file}${counter}"
            (( counter++ ))
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: This will break miserably if filenames contain spaces or glob characters. Don't use!